# Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_Practice\application\controllers\news.php on line 11

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote a small application from CodeIgnitor user guide but when I run it, display the given message

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_Practice\application\controllers\news.php on line 11
```

The code is

```
class News extends CI_Controller{
  public function _construct()    
  {
     parent::_construct();   
     $this->load->model('news_model');
  }
  public function index()
  {
  $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news(); 
     $data['title'] = 'News archive';

     $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
     $this->load->view('news/index',$data);
     $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
}
```

Line 11 is :

```
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
```

Comment: Would you write your model code as well.

Comment: did you load the news_model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, i could see that you've missed one '**_**'(underscore) while defining your construct.
It has to be as below:

```
public function __construct()    
{
  parent::__construct();   
  $this->load->model('news_model');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `model` by getting your `Instance` as well:

```
class News extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct()    
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->CI = & get_instance();   
   $this->CI->load->model('news_model');
 }
 public function index()
 {
   $data['news'] = $this->CI->news_model->get_news(); 
   $data['title'] = 'News archive';

   $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
   $this->load->view('news/index',$data);
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }
}
```