# Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm following CodeIgniter's User Guide, and I'm having problems with this section http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

It's reporting error `Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object` at the first line of the `index` method. Looks like if the loading of the model wasn't working. I've changed all the `news_model` for `News_model` for checking if that was the reason, but anything changes.

There was the same question two years ago [Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_Practice\application\controllers\news.php on line 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208713/call-to-a-member-function-get-news-on-a-non-object-in-c-xampp-htdocs-codeigni) but the solution in that case is not working for me, as my call to construct is correctly defined.

applications/controllers/News.php

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function __contruct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news(); //<-----------------------
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug = NULL) {
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item'])){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

applications/models/News_model.php

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the call `$this->load->model('news_model');` right before the line in question and see if it really loads.

Comment: @Jan it does work, so the problem is in the construct. But where?

Comment: Shouldn't `url_helper` be just `url`?

Comment: @Tpojka seems irrelevant, just changed and same error. Anyway, the tutorial used `url_helper`

Comment: Try with `$this->load->model('News_model');` than use as `$this->News_model->get_news();`.

Comment: @Tpojka I tried that already. I stated that on the body of the question.

Comment: See my answer, you had a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this is worth an answer, but you had a typo (the s was missing in `__construct()` so it was never called). Additionally, the `url_helper` is just called `url` but you did not get an error as it was never called.

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
```

Comment: lawl! I have have syntax highlighting and didn't notice it wasn't highlighted but the one right after it was... Now that it's fixed, I don't get an error with `url_helper`, so maybe that's correct?

Comment: @yzT Glad it worked out. Additionally, change the `url_helper` to `url` and remove the call to the model from `index()`.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `__construct` in the controller... you're missing an s